# How to find all the True Positives,negatives and False Positives and Negatives considering all the classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I am able to do the same for smaller dataset where I know the desired outputs

For example:
I have the dataset:

```
y_true=[1,1,0,1]
y_pred=[1,0,0,0]
```

I am able to write the function for find all the true and false positives and negatives:

```
def measures(y_pred, y_true):
    TP = 0
    FP = 0
    TN = 0
    FN = 0

    for i in range(len(y_pred)): 
        if y_true[i]==y_pred[i]==1:
           TP += 1
        if y_pred[i]==1 and y_true[i]!=y_pred[i]:
           FP += 1
        if y_true[i]==y_pred[i]==0:
           TN += 1
        if y_pred[i]==0 and y_true[i]!=y_pred[i]:
           FN += 1

    return(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

But what if I intend to find the same for multiple labels,something like this:

```
y_true=[1,2,0,1,3]
y_pred=[1,0,3,2,1]
```

So I want to find all the TP_total,TN_total,FP_total and FN_total considering each label `'1','2','0','3'`

How can I do that

Comment: see confusion matrix,columns will represent actual class  and rows will represent predicted classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged `Scikit-Learn` in your question, you can get very good insights about the True/False Positives and Negatives in addition to a variety of Classification Metrics such as the Precision, Recall, Accuracy, F1-Score and Support ... straightforwardly by using the [Classification Report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) and the [Confusion Matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) which returns what you want (example):

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]).ravel()
```

Or you can plot it by using [Plot Confusion Matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix).

(*Examples are in the links*)

---

Below are some samples:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Python, the scikit-learn package (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) provides a function which will return the confusion matrix of a classification problem (binary or multiclass), the `confusion_matrix` function (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html). With the confusion matrix, you may obtain true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives for your problem.

The figure below (retrieved from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_display_object_visualization.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-display-object-visualization-py) illustrates a confusion matrix for binary classification produced with scikit-learn. In the figure, false positives are on the top-left (140), true positives are on the bottom-right (5), false negatives are on bottom-left (39) and false positives are on top-right (3).

[image: Confusion Matrix - Binary Classification]

In a multi-class setting, the interpretation is similar. However, your errors will be associated to multiple classes, not only a single class (such as in binary classification setting).

I hope this may be of help!